# how to call the screen after the thread is finished

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Loading class where I did the whole Thread process and calls this class where it should perform a sample processing a login screen.

I have a class where I should query data by searching an API and then display the data in a DisplayAlert. The problem is that the displayAlert appears before the loading process finishes and does not perform a wait process.

```
private void Escuta()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (Appconfig.Processando == false)

                try
                {
                    PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
                    Appconfig.t_Processamento.Abort();

                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Appconfig.t_Processamento.Abort();
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.Wait()` to completed task & than display alert

```
Task.Run(async () => { listStudent = await objLogin.GetStudent(parameter); }).Wait();
//here DisplayAlert
```